# iOS input string slighly different (fault tolerant search)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, search-engine

I want to handle a little mistakes from keyboard input from the user (This is a concept phase so I don't have any component's yet, so feel free to suggest one).

Let's assume that I have `CoreData` entity with 1000 inputs. I want to search for only one attribute. And I want behavior like in `UIFetchedResultController` (this could be one, but I also can simulate it behavior).

Once agin, let's assume that this is fruit entity contains attribute `name` and the user searched for it. He wants to search `banana` but he enters `bansna` (or `vanana`) by mistake. I want to still show him "banana" phase.

How can I do this? This can be done using `NSPredicate`? Can I manipulate this "tolerance" ?

I use 1000 number of entries early, the speed of searching I assume depends of this tolerance and database size. So for this maybe i should move from mobile to REST service? Looking for advice here also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core Data fetch requests do not support a "fault tolerant" search. The available 
comparison operators for strings are

- `==` for exact equality,
- `CONTAINS`, `BEGINSWITH`, `ENDSWITH` for substring search,
- `LIKE` for simple wildcard matching,
- `MATCHES` for regular expression search.

But for a "fault tolerant" search you need some advanced comparison algorithm like the
[Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), which can be used to determine
if one string is "close to" another string (and there are probably more algorithms).

Since a Core Data fetch request cannot use a "Objective-C based" predicate
(such as `predicateWithBlock`), this means that you have to fetch all objects and
then apply the fault tolerant comparison method.

Comment: That's a very very good answer. I would also say that CONTAINS and MATCHES have a major cost in term of performances.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! And thanks for the term "fault tolerant search" really useful for digging more information.

Comment: @Kuba: You are welcome! Other search terms you can try are "fuzzy (or approximate) string matching".

Answer (score 1):

Write predicate as: `WHERE name like '?anana' or name like 'v?nana' or name like 'va?ana' or name like 'van?na' or name like 'vana?a' or name like 'vanan?'`